# Fedora (GNOME 3) copy & paste is unreliable

Tags: fedora, copy-paste, clipboard, gnome3

About a third to half of the time that I do Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V, it fails to copy the selected text to the clipboard. If I then go and do Ctrl+C again, it works the second time. How can I make it work reliably?

Observations:

1. I don't think I have a clipboard manager running. At least, I know that clipit is not installed.
2. The issue does not depend on the application. It can occur with any application, and also for text being copied from one application to another.
3. The issue is with copying, not with pasting. If I have text already in the clipboard, when this issue occurs, the selected text does not get copied when I do Ctrl+C - I still have the old text in the clipboard, not the new text that should have been copied.
4. The issue is not a keyboard issue. It happens just the same if I select "Copy" with the mouse. It also happens when I do a cut (Ctrl-X) in which case the selected text is just deleted instead of cut to the clipboard.

Comment: I have observed the same phenomenon since I've upgraded from F29 to F31. Are you on F31? Did you observe this before?

Comment: OK I've found this report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1769236

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat yes, I'm on F31 (although I don't remember if I had this problem before 31 as I upgraded to 31 shortly after acquiring this laptop). And thanks for the link to the bug report! If I had a Fedora account, I would also write a "me too" comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently switched from Wayland to X11, and the issue seems to have disappeared since doing that. So I will assume this is a current problem with Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this issue, and if you use (Shift-Ctrl-C) and (Shift-Ctrl-v), it will always copy and paste last input.

Comment: Thanks, but Shift-Ctrl-C and Shift-Ctrl-V can have totally different meanings to Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V depending on the application. For example, in IntelliJ IDEA's editing window, Shift-Ctrl-V means "paste from history".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is SELinux policy.
Try changing SELinux mode from 'enforcing' to 'permissive' and see if that helps.

```
# sudo setenforce permissive
```

Comment: Thanks, but I may have already found a solution. I've recently switched from Wayland (the default on Fedora) to X11 and the issue has not appeared since I did that, so I'm happy to stay with X11. I'll make a note of it to let other users know.